# Cannot find Extras after installing Google Play Services SDK

Tags: android, sdk, google-play

I'm following this:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Under "Install the Google Play Services SDK" Step 4, it says to import files in this path:
/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/

My problem is, I don't have that path.

On my Mac, I have this path:
Applications//extras

but there's no google folder under extras.

Is this step even necessary?  I'm using ADT Build: v22.6.2-1085508.

Thanks.

Gerard

Comment: check under the android-sdk/extras....

Comment: the path is "android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib"

Comment: Goto Android SDK Manager and confirm that you have downloaded Google Play Services. You can see it inside Extra section.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found my mistake.  First of all, I was looking in the wrong place.  I don't know why, but Applications[adtfolder] also contains a folder called Extras.  It's the wrong place.

Go determine the actual path, go to Android SDK Manager, then hover your mouse on Google Play services (under Extras).  It will have a hint box that shows the path as Location.